# Electrophilic Aromatic Substitution of phenols

Tags: organic-chemistry

What happens if 2,4,6-tribromophenol is forced to undergo further bromination?

In phenol, the benzene ring is activated towards electrophilic substitution. Therefore, phenol on bromination gives 2,4,6-tribromophenol. If now, 2, 4, 6-tribromophenol is forced to undergo bromination, the group attached to the benzene nucleus makes phenol not suitable to undergo Friedel–Crafts reaction due to adduct formation with Lewis acid.

Comment: Please make your last statement *If now, 2, 4, 6-tribromophenol is forced to undergo bromination the group attached to benzene nucleus makes phenol not suitable to undergo Friedel Craft reaction due to adduct formation with Lewis acid.* a bit more clear.

Comment: 2,4,6-Tribromophenol may be converted to the tetrabromide, 2,4,4,6-tetrabromo-hexa-2,5-dien-1-one. It is an effective, crystalline brominating agent of enols. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/jo061522l/suppl_file/jo061522lsi20060905_042700.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Way overthinking this.  [Kohn](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed020p117) reports that 2,4,6-tribromophenol can be further brominated to pentabromophenol by adding more bromine and an iron catalyst.  Subsequently the pentabromophenol is oxidized by fuming nitric acid to give a fully brominated quinone.